# How to save remote GIF to album in iOS in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, gif

Thanks for reading, I am trying to save remote GIF to system album in React Native in iOS.

**I have try the following ways but all of them saving GIFs as static images.**

I create a new React Native project of 0.62.2 to run these code

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.7.2",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  }
```

1. Save GIF directly by CameraRoll.
   Not working because https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll/issues/16

```js
const uri = 'https://i.loli.net/2020/05/28/YKaCdO1pexuThbN.gif'
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri);
```

2. Download GIF firstly by react-native-fs

```js
const img = 'https://i.loli.net/2020/05/28/YKaCdO1pexuThbN.gif'
const storeLocation = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}`;
const pathName = `${new Date().getTime()}_babycam_moji.gif`;
const downloadPath = `${storeLocation}${pathName}`;
const ret = RNFS.downloadFile({
  fromUrl: img,
  toFile: downloadPath,
});
ret.promise.then((res) => {
  console.log('res', res);
  if (res && res.statusCode === 200) {
    const promise = CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(
      `file://${downloadPath}`,
    );
    promise.then(() => {});
  } else {
  }
});
```

3. download GIF firstly by rn-fetch-blob

```js
RNFetchBlob.config({appendExt: 'gif', fileCache: true})
  .fetch('GET', img)
  .then((res) => {
  console.log('res', res.path());
  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(res.path());
});
```

**How can I save GIFs to album in iOS in react-native?**

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any workaround ?